# what is the order of boolean logic in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to use two Not and one and in booleans to test if the variable is neither upper case nor lower case.

I used this code so far but it didn't work as required:

```
else if ((x[i]) !== (x[i].toUpperCase()) && (x[i]!== x[i].toLowerCase()) ){
    x.splice(x[i], 1);
}
```

This code was for a function that sorts entered strings yet uppercase are sorted first.

Here is the full code, I am also open to understanding better ways to create this function apart from boolean logic and the array methods I used.

```
function alpha(str){ // United States

    var x = str.split(""); // [U,n,i,t,e,d,S,t,a,t,e,s]
    var cap = [];
    var small = [];


    for (var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){

        if (x[i] == x[i].toUpperCase()){
            cap.push(x[i]);
        }

        else if ((x[i]) !== (x[i].toUpperCase()) && (x[i]!== x[i].toUpperCase()) )  {
            x.splice(x[i], 1);
        }
        else {small.push(x[i]);}
}


    var z = cap.sort();
    var y = small.sort();
    return z.concat(y).join("");

}
```

Please note the second else if statement is only useful because the code adds an empty space string at the beginning of the output, I'm not sure where it comes from, so please let me know if you have any idea how to sort this even without using the second else if.

Comment: Why would you have a condition which `&&`'s together two exactly identical conditions? Why would you test for non-uppercase when you just tested for uppercase? What are you trying to do with the `splice`? `splice` takes an index, not an array element or letter.

Comment: sorry it's meant to be toLowerCase, just a typo
I am testing for both non-upper and non-lower as well to be removed, because for some reason when I enter input of "United Stated" I would get " SUadeeinsttt", so this was to splice/remove this space,

Comment: so should the index of splice be indexOf(x[i]) ?
I know it's a sophisticated way for such a simple function but it's all I can think of as a learner

Comment: Please give a couple of cases of inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: there is only 1 test input which is "United States" and it should be "SUadeeinsttt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all programming languages (as far as i know), boolean expressions are always evaluated from the left to the right with brackets of course.

So in the following example my_func() is called first, and then if there is the chance that the complete expression becomes true my_other_func() is called

```
if (my_func() && my_other_func()) {
    // I only get here if my_func() AND my_other_func() return true
    // If my_func() returns false, my_other_func() is never called
}
```

The same is true for the "or" operator in the following example

```
if (my_func() || my_other_func()) {
    // I only get here if my_func() OR my_other_func() return true
    // If my_func() returns true, my_other_func() is not called
}
```

So back to your code, in details this part (I reformated it a bit for better readability):

```
    if (x[i] == x[i].toUpperCase()){
        // only uppercase here
        cap.push(x[i]);
    } else if (x[i] !== x[i].toUpperCase() && x[i] !== x[i].toUpperCase()) {
        // tested twice the same thing, so Im really sure that its not uppercase :D
        // only lowercase here
        x.splice(x[i], 1);
    } else {
        // I will never reach this
        small.push(x[i]);
    }
```

Im not sure what you want to do, but I hope the comments help to understand your code.

Comment: Thanks alot for you answe chickahoona. the second .toUpperCase() was a typo it was supposed to be .toLowerCase() , can you please explain how the code would work given that I corrected the typo?

Answer (score 1):

In the ASCII table, upper case letters come first. That's why they come first when you sort alphabetically. Here's a link to a page on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) that shows the table with the upper case letters appearing first and their numerical equivalents. It's even printable.

Also, I took the liberty of simplifying your code a little. Seems like .splice() was not necessary.

```
function alpha( str ) {

    var x = str.split(""); // [U,n,i,t,e,d,S,t,a,t,e,s]
    var cap = [];
    var small = [];
    var length = x.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (x[i] === x[i].toUpperCase()) {
            cap.push(x[i]);
        } else if (x[i] === x[i].toLowerCase()) {
            small.push(x[i]);
        }           

    }

    return cap.sort().concat(small.sort()).join("");

}
```

Maybe explain what you're trying to do? It most likely has been done before in some form and you definitely came to the right place to find an answer.

Comment: Thanks alot for Your answer Patrick.
I thought .sort() is case-Agnostic, so I did the whole .toUpper/LowerCase to make the upper case ones come first, however the reason I used .splice() was to delete this " " empty space string from the array before joining it, however, I just learned now about .trim()

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

```js
var str = "United States";

function alpha(str) {
  return str.split('').sort().join('');
}

alert(alpha(str));
```

Comment: yes that's exactly what I was trying to do minus .trim() which is why I used the .toUpper/LowerCase, thank you so much for your answer torazaburo, I really appreciate how people are patient with a newbie like me :)